# How can i change the url with jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm totally new in jquery and userscripts.
 Can someone help me with this:

```
<a class="image is-100x100" href="/profile/myprofile">
   <img class="profile-img" src="https://cdn.blabla/folder/blurr/100x100/content/166634.jpg" alt="">
</a>
```

I want to change one word in the url. (**blurr**) in to (**default**)

```
<a class="image is-100x100" href="/profile/myprofile">
   <img class="profile-img" src="https://cdn.blabla/folder/default/100x100/content/166634.jpg" alt="">
</a>
```

How can i do this?

```
$(function () {
    $(".profile-img").html($(".profile-img").html().replace("blurr", "default"));

    });
```

EDIT:

I want an tapermonkey script not an script for concole.

Comment: $(".profile-img").attr('src',$(".profile-img").attr('src').replace("blurr", "default"));

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
$(".profile-img").attr("src").replace('blurr', 'default');
```

Find the snippet below:

```js
var updatedSrc = $(".profile-img").attr("src").replace('blurr', 'default');
$(".profile-img").attr("src",updatedSrc);
alert($(".profile-img").attr("src"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="image is-100x100" href="/profile/myprofile">123
   <img class="profile-img" src="https://cdn.blabla/folder/blurr/100x100/content/166634.jpg" alt=""/>
</a>
```

*Update:*

You must use your script after document is properly loaded. So I just moved your script at the end of the html body.

Review below example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<a class="image is-100x100" href="/profile/myprofile">
   <img class="profile-img" src="https://cdn.blabla/folder/blurr/100x100/content/166634.jpg" alt="">
</a>
<script>
(function() {
 var src= $('img').attr('src');
    src = src.replace("blurr", "default")
    $('img').attr('src',src);
console.log($('img').attr('src'));
})();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Execution of script 'New Userscript' failed! $(...).attr(...) is undefined

Comment: Have you verified Jquery is available on the page?

Comment: Yes.. Both in my userscript and on site is Jquery is available
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>

Comment: Have you verified the snippet ?

Comment: verified the snippet ?

I'm new :S

Comment: I have added code snippet in my answer. Just click "Run Code Snippet " button and review it.

Comment: Yes it works but not on the site..Here is the hole script: https://pastebin.com/ikWs109q

Comment: Find updated answer. I have added one more snippet using your code

Comment: I have find an site with the same template as i try on. Try to change lctfxx to default on this and see if it works for you. https://www.diskretflirt.com/splash

Comment: I have tested with below code and it's working perfect.
`var src= $('.profile-img').attr('src');
    src = src.replace("lctfxx", "default")
    $('.profile-img').attr('src',src);`

Comment: ERROR: Execution of script 'New Userscript' failed! src is undefined 

I have tried in firefox and chrome

Comment: I think it should be script load related issue. Review your code and find the exact cause of the issue. This way I am not able to help you Properly.

Comment: In browser concole it's partly works. All profiles has the same img :S
But when i try this two lines
var updatedSrc = $(".profile-img").attr("src").replace('blurr', 'default');
$(".profile-img").attr("src",updatedSrc);
 in tampermonkey i get:

https://pastebin.com/MZjXqMaM

Comment: Create example using your code and share it using snippet/any other way.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/mZ87nVtS is my userscript
https://pastebin.com/LmrkjMMi is the error and i use firefox and  tampermonkey

Comment: Only Jquery does not help me to find exact cause. You need to provide whole page code including html in which you are facing the issue

Comment: https://pastebin.com/qEQtLWhV <-- HTML. And i try with tapermonkey with the script i posted here https://pastebin.com/mZ87nVtS

Comment: Create example using your code in JsFiddle and share link here

Comment: My best guess is that i need to add .each() somehow to change all profile images.???

Answer (score 2):

You have to acceed to the `SRC atribute`

```
$(".profile-img").attr('src',$(".profile-img").attr('src').replace("blurr", "default"));
```

Comment: Execution of script 'New Userscript' failed! $(...).attr(...) is undefined

Answer (score 1):

1. Get a URL using jQuery attr function which return the value of attribute.

   var url = $(".profile-img").attr("src");
2. Replace the value in string you want to replace

   var editedUrl = url.replace("blurr", "default");
3. Set the new value as src using same attr setter function

   $(".profile-img").attr("src",editedUrl);

Combined code will look like

```
var url = $(".profile-img").attr("src");
var editedUrl = url.replace("blurr", "default");
$(".profile-img").attr("src",editedUrl);
```

Referance for javascript replace function,

https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FQI3GTEMQDE6

Comment: Execution of script 'New Userscript' failed! url is undefined

Comment: Are you setting src out of scope?

Comment: out of scope? The site hase multi profile-img if it helps?

Comment: Updated answer for variable name

Answer (score 1):

Change image `src` using `attr`.

```js
var src= $('img').attr('src');
src = src.replace("blurr", "default")
$('img').attr('src',src);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="image is-100x100" href="/profile/myprofile">123
   <img class="profile-img" src="https://cdn.blabla/folder/blurr/100x100/content/166634.jpg" alt=""/>
</a>
```

Run the above snippet and inspect you can see URL is change.

[image: Out put result]

Comment: Execution of script 'New Userscript' failed! src is undefined

Comment: seems like  js is not lode properly .

Comment: Run this code in console and see what it say using F12 on your site .

Comment: First line  give undefined

Comment: What do you mean 1st line .

Comment: var src= $('img').attr('src');

Comment: this site have the same template but here is blurr lctfxx.. So on this site lctfxx--->default https://www.diskretflirt.com/splash

Answer (score 1):

All answers above use call the `attr()` function twice. This doesn't make the code worse but it's a bit too long. You can instead use a callback to shorten it:

```
$(".profile-img").attr("src", (_, old) => old.replace('blur', 'default'));
```

The second argument of `attr` here is a function which returns the new value based on the old one.

http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-function